# Iterating over a vector defined in a struct

Tags: c++, vector, tree

I am working on a non-binary tree structure, and so for that I have a struct defined as follows which has a data and all it's child are in a vector called child.

```
struct node{
   string data;
   vector< node* > child;
   vector<node*>::iterator i
   int Count;
};
```

I have another function that I have defined to print the child in the vectors, but I can't get the iterator working

```
void printTree(node* &a){

    for(a->i = a->child.begin(); a->i !=a->child.end();++i)
        cout << *(a->i)->data <<endl;
}
```

I am getting an error that the iterator isn't defined when printTree is called. I tried defining the iterator inside printTree function but I keep getting an error. Any suggestions on how should I change my code?

Comment: why do you need an iterator for every single node?

Comment: Is there a reason you've got the iterator inside the node?

Comment: Probably not the solution but in the for loop you're incrementing `i` instead of `a->i`.

Comment: I tried defining an iterator inside the main function and passing it to the printTree function, but  I get an error. I also tried defining it inside printTree function but still it says the iterator isn't defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take the iterator out of your `node` structure.

```
void printTree(node* &a)
{
    for( vector<node*>::iterator i = a->child.begin(); i != a->child.end(); i++ )
    {
        cout << (*i)->data << endl;
    }
}
```

---

**[edit]**

Even I confused myself when I wrote this answer.  Quite often I save myself from ugly and potentially confusing iterator dereferencing by doing this inside the loop:

```
node * n = *i;
cout << n->data << endl;
```

More generally, if I have `SomeContainer<SomeType>`, I do this:

```
for( SomeContainer<SomeType>::iterator i = foo.begin(); i != foo.end(); i++ )
{
    SomeType & val = *i;
    // ...
}
```

The above approach is particularly handy when you are iterating through a `map` and have to use `i->second` to get your data instead of `*i`.

Comment: I tried this and I am getting the follow error " request for member 'data' in '* i.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator-><node**, std::vector<node*> >()', which is of pointer type 'node*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)"
Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: Whoops sorry about that.  Need to put parentheses around `*i`.  When you do `*i` it dereferences the iterator into the contained type (`node*`), then we use the arrow operator to get the `data` member.  Please see the edited answer.